# can i run a cronjob of a python file in virtualenv?

Tags: cron, cron-task

I have a small script inside a python file that I want to run using cronjob

the python file runs only in virtualenv

how can I make it so that I can run this file using a cronjob?
so far I ran  crontab -e
and saved this line

```
0 */2 * * *  /Documents/scrapping/run.py
```

this file is supposed to run every 2 hours

now when I checked syslog the cronjob didn't run

what am I doing wrong?
I assume it has something to do with virtualenv-

why am I not seeing an output in syslog?

Comment: you will need to put that python script in a shell script so that you can activate ur virtualenv and run the script after. Alternatively, you may use a docker container.

Comment: alternatively, you will need to append your virtualenv site-packages path to your PYTHONPATH environment variable. so that your python will look into those folders for additional packages/modules

Comment: how do i convert a python script in a shell script

Answer (score 0):

Scheduling cron jobs with python in virtual environments check these steps with `bash file` with run the `python script`.[Python Script](https://marquinsmith.com/2017/11/02/scheduling-cron-jobs-with-python-in-virtual-environments/)

And for cron setting check the `crontab` configuration to execute your script.[Cron Confi](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CronHowto)

Thanks